# Serilog, one file sink writing, one is leaving a blank file

Tags: serilog

So I have a simple method to make logger instances for me.

It is as follows

```
protected ILogger GetIndividualLogger(ILogger parentLogger, LogEventLevel minimumLevel, string RootDir, string Type, string Name, bool shouldBuffer, bool shouldBeShared, TimeSpan flushToDiskInterval)
{
    var LogAllFile = $"{RootDir}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}{Name}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}RAL-{Type}-{Name}-.log";
    var LogWarningFile = $"{RootDir}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}{Name}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}Warnings{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}RAL-{Type}-{Name}-.log";

    ILogger logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Is(minimumLevel)
        .Enrich.WithDemystifiedStackTraces()
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.Logger(parentLogger))
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.File(LogAllFile, outputTemplate: SerilogHereHelper.TemplateForHere, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, buffered: shouldBuffer, shared: shouldBeShared))
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.File(LogWarningFile, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Warning, outputTemplate: SerilogHereHelper.TemplateForHere, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, buffered: shouldBuffer, shared: shouldBeShared, flushToDiskInterval: flushToDiskInterval))
        .CreateLogger();
    return logger;
}
```

Here is an example call to GetIndividualLogger

```
GetIndividualLogger(parentLogger: mainLogger, minimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information, RootDir: _stackLightLogPath, Type: "Stack Light", Name: "Stack Light 1", shouldBuffer: true, shouldBeShared: false, flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSecond(2))
```

The warning level sink will write, but then the other sink, which is usually set to debug or information will create an empty file but never add any entries to it.

I would expect **both files** to have **all warning level entries** or above.
I would expect the "LogAllFile" to have all entries at or above the minimum level, but it is blank.

Is there something wrong with my logger config? or is my problem elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to the problem was silly. The warning log was being flushed to disk every 2 seconds, but the main log file was not so all I needed to do was to just pass a value in for flushToDiskInterval

```
.WriteTo.Async(a => a.File(LogAllFile, outputTemplate: SerilogHereHelper.TemplateForHere, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, buffered: shouldBuffer, shared: shouldBeShared, flushToDiskInterval: flushToDiskInterval))
```